# Encrypting whole disk with Luks (instead of one big encrypted partition)

Tags: partition, encryption, luks

### Context

Encrypting whole new external hard drive with Luks.
I.e. it is not a system drive (will be used only to store data, not to boot the OS), and it is completely blank.

### Observation

All descriptions that I found about how to achieve this go along the lines of:

1. create a new partition, which is the same size as the whole disk
2. encrypt that partition

Some examples:

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/500987):

> Creating a new encrypted partition:
>
> [...]
>
> Encrypting an existing partition

Or [here](https://lobotuerto.com/blog/how-to-setup-full-disk-encryption-on-a-secondary-hdd-in-linux/#create-the-partition-table).

### Question

Is it possible to encrypt the **whole disk**, instead of having one big encrypted partition?

Probably the answer will be ***no***, so the real question is **why not**?

### In other words

What would happen if instead of typing

```
sudo cryptsetup -v -y luksFormat /dev/sda1
```

I would type

```
sudo cryptsetup -v -y luksFormat /dev/sda
```

(without having created `sda1`)?

Comment: The module to decrypt this filesystem need to read `/etc/crypttab` which is impossible if you encrypt the entire disk (boot disk)

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I said explicitly this is **not** a boot disk, but a data disk. Also, it is external (I don't know much about how `crypttab` works, but surely I can mount a new external encrypted HDD, even if it was not in `crypttab` before, right?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`cryptsetup` FAQ](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#2-setup) mentions whole-disk encryption using LUKS. Basically, `cryptsetup` doesn’t care what the LUKS device is, partition, disk, or loop device, so you can use whichever is appropriate.

```
sudo cryptsetup -v -y luksFormat /dev/sda
```

will create a LUKS container using all of `/dev/sda`.

Section 2.2 of the FAQ recommends this for external disks:

> Fully encrypted raw block device: For this, put LUKS on the raw
>   device (e.g. `/dev/sdb`) and put a filesystem into the LUKS container,
>   no partitioning whatsoever involved.  This is very suitable for
>   things like external USB disks used for backups or offline
>   data-storage.

Note that `cryptsetup` doesn’t need `/etc/crypttab`.

Comment: Yes, I do this for my external drives. Some desktop environments offer you an "Unlock" option automatically when the drive is plugged in. If yours doesn't do it you can use `udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda` from the command line.